# Not getting Facebook User ID

Tags: php, file, facebook-php-sdk, userid

I'm trying to get the Facebook ID of the current user logged in and using my app so that it can be written to a database along with some other information.

I've tested it countless times for myself and it will get my ID and write it to the database, but if I ask someone else to use it... It won't get the ID of the user of my application...

Am I missing any extended permissions for this? This is all I have so far to get the user id.

Thanks.

```
<?php include ('includes/php/facebook.php'); ?>

<?php

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));

?>

<?php

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $userId = $user;
    //some code here...
?>
```

Comment: where are you logging the user in and having them grant your app access to their account info?

Comment: Nowhere. I'm just getting the user's id... So it would appear that authentication is the problem... it would explain it

Comment: Yep that's your problem. Check out @mazzucci's answer or the SDK docs for an example.

Comment: I have the same issue and I am logged in and viewing the data through the iframe. I am assuming that facebook sdk is suppose to pick up my information if I am viewing from the iframe. and i would assume the minimum information would atleaset provide the user id.

Answer (score 1):

If $userID is 0 or null, it means that the user is not authenticated.

```
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array("domain" => 'www.myurl.com'));
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => 'publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages'));
}
```

You can download the SDK from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

It contains several examples.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> By default, the user is asked to authorize the app to access basic
>   information that is available publicly or by default on Facebook. If
>   your app needs more than this basic information to function, you must
>   request specific permissions from the user. This is accomplished by
>   adding a scope parameter to the OAuth Dialog request followed by comma
>   separated list of the required permissions. The following example
>   shows how to ask for access to user's email address and their news
>   feed:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream
```